# Could not upload XCTest package to Google Cloud Storage for Firebase Test Lab

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to create a new test on Firebase Test Lab.

When I upload the XCTest package file, I have this error:

> The file could not be uploaded to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). This
>   issue might be caused by incorrect GCS permissions.

[image]

How can I solve this issue or have more information about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error looks to be due to missing permissions for your users. To run a test in Test Lab through the Console your user needs to have the **Editor** role permissions. This is the case because Test Lab is creating a "free" GCS Bucket for you that it shares with your project and allows to be written only by **Owner** or **Editor** roles of your project.

For more details see the [Firebase IAM permissions sections for Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#test-lab). It gives you some additional details on how to make it work via **gcloud** with your own GCS bucket and more restrictive roles/permissions in case you cannot or don't want to grant yourself the **Editor** role.